# Problems compiling Angular 8 CLI project with amcharts4

Tags: angular, amcharts, amcharts4, angular8

I updated my application which used @amcharts/amcharts4@4.3.5 to Angular 8 and now have problems compiling it.

Already updated amcharts to version 4.4.10. But the problem remains.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/export/Export.js 68:24
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (68:24)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|             switch (_a.label) {
|                 case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, Promise.all([
>                         import(/* webpackChunkName: "pdfmake" */ "pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js"),
|                         import(/* webpackChunkName: "pdfmake" */ "../../pdfmake/vfs_fonts")
|                     ])];
```

Answer (score 7):

This workaround did it for me:

```
npm install --save acorn@6.1.1
npm dedupe
```

---

The issue is on NPMs side, check here:

https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1002

Found this in the AmCharts documentation that lead me to a the above workaround:

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/integrations/using-webpack/

Comment: Works great!  Saved huge amounts of time figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this issue:

1. Delete the node modules folder  `rm -rf node_modules`
2. Delete the package-lock JSON file `rm -f package-lock.json`
3. Instead of installing the packages using NPM, use YARN
   `yarn install`

It seems that NPM has a problem with the dependencies :/